# Code first migrations: read sql from file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first, entity-framework-migrations

I following a post from ADO.NET team Code First Migrations: [Alpha 3 ‘No-Magic’ Walkthrough](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/21/code-first-migrations-alpha-3-no-magic-walkthrough.aspx)

I'm trying to read a file with sql for a migration in a asp.net mvc web application. I'm using sql method. The problem is that no matter what I do I can not get a root path to my project. I always get 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\'

Could someone point me a way to open my file?

Thanks.

**Edited**

> ```
> public partial class AddMembership : DbMigration
> {
>     public override void Up()
>     {
>         //var file = File.OpenText(System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName() + "Model/Schema/membership-up.sql");
>         //var file = File.OpenText(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "Model/Schema/membership-up.sql");
>         //var path = HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath("/Models/Schema/membership-up.sql");
>         var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Models/Schema/membership-up.sql");
>         Sql(file.ReadToEnd());
>     }
>
>     public override void Down()
>     {
>         // ....
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Hi marc_s, I posted some code I have tried.

Comment: OK, two things: (1) do that `/Models` folder and the .sql file really exist in your deployed ASP.NET site?? And (2): you most likely need to use a tilde-based mapping: `.MapPath("~/Models/Schema/membership-up.sql")`

Comment: hey marc_s, thanks for your reply. Yes, that folder exists but in my dev project. I also tried with '~'. As I commented in jdross reply, Using MapPath throws an exception. Since this code is called in  Package Manager Console I am not sure if we can go throw HttpContext.

Comment: What if you just specify the whole, full path, possibly read from a config file or something? If you're calling that in a package manager console, that should work (no Server.MapPath needed).

Comment: I thought about it, but I would like to have a solution independent of my project path since this code is used in a team environment. I could not found in .NET API something to get my project path, at least without throwing System.NullReferenceException.

Answer (score 0):

What about using Server.MapPath

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632(v=vs.90).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Unfortunately when I run Update-Database from Package Manager Console, HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath throws an exception. I also tried HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath but I don't think that this console tool has an HttpContext.

Answer (score 0):

To run the migration directly from the site you could add this code

```
var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(new Settings());
dbMigrator.Update();
```

To run migrations from either process (IIS vs Package Manager Console) you could check first if Server object is created before using Server.MapPath, this way you'd recognize if you're under IIS or under Package Manager Console. 
If Server object is null you're under Package Manager Console so you could use something more appropriate to get your current path from like

```
Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

So I would replace this code

```
var path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Models/Schema/membership-up.sql");
```

with something like this

```
String path;
if (HttpContext.Current.Server != null) {
    path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Models/Schema/membership-up.sql");
} else {
    path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "Models/Schema/membership-up.sql");
}
```

Comment: Hey Eugenio. Only today I saw that you have replied. The problem is that I want to run it form Package Manager Console, while I am in dev environment and HttpContext context does not exists. I have to see if Microsoft provides something for this scenario in beta version.